# How to pass userid in interceptor Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, rest, restful-authentication, angular-http-interceptors

Oke,

I have an Angular 8 application and I have an HttpMaintenanceInterceptor and I am not using cookies for it. but a:

getAccessToken method in the authService, like this:

```
  getAccessToken(): string {
    return this._user ? this._user.access_token : null;
  }
```

and I have a get method. A get method looks like this:

```
getDossierEntry(type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType);
}
```

But the problem now is that the the propertie:

```
patientUUID
```

is always null. OR this is the output of it:

```
http://localhost:4200/api/patient/$%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical"
```

So I try to sent the patientUUID in the HttpMaintenanceInterceptor.

The HttpMaintenanceInterceptor looks like this:

```
export class HttpMaintenanceInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  needsAuthenticatedUser = true;
  route: string;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken = this.auth.getAccessToken();

    if (accessToken != null) {      
      console.log(accessToken);
      const duplicate = request.clone({
        setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer  ${accessToken}` }

      });

      const user$ = this.auth.loginStatus()
      .pipe( take( 1 ) );

       user$.pipe(
         map( user => {
          console.log('hello there nice to see you!!');
          let parsedRoute = this.route;
          if ( this.needsAuthenticatedUser ) {
            if ( !user ) {
              throw Error( 'Tried to call api that requires login without a user profile present' );
            } else {
              parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{userId}', user.profile.sub);
           //   console.log('User Sub ' + user.profile.sub);
              console.log('User participant ' + user.profile.participant);

              parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant);
            }
          }
          return environment.ApiOrigin + parsedRoute;
        } ),
      );


      return next.handle(duplicate);
    } else {     
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  } 
}
```

But I dont get the patientUUID.

But I get the accessToken:    console.log(accessToken); looks like this:

```
mIwM2U2MGNhMzgwYzczMzA2NjIcHM6Ly9k.....
```

So my question is how to pass the patientUUID? so that in the api requests the patientUUID will not be null anymore.

Thank you

oke, I changed to this:

```
getDossierEntry(type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>(`/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/` + entryType);
}
```

but that is not the problem I think.

Because the problem is this:

console.log('hello there nice to see you!!');

It doesn't reach that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backquote should be used instead of simple quote

> '/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/'

should rather be

```
`/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/`
```

The same thing holds when using `parsedRoute.replace`

```
const user$ = this.auth.loginStatus()
      .pipe( take( 1 ) );    
       user$.pipe(
         map( user => {
          console.log('hello there nice to see you!!');
          let parsedRoute = this.route;
          if ( this.needsAuthenticatedUser ) {
            if ( !user ) {
              throw Error( 'Tried to call api that requires login without a user profile present' );
            } else {
              parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{userId}', user.profile.sub);
           //   console.log('User Sub ' + user.profile.sub);
              console.log('User participant ' + user.profile.participant);

              parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant);
            }
          }
          return environment.ApiOrigin + parsedRoute;
        } ),
      );
```

This part of the code will never be executed because you're not subscribing to the observable. That is why the value of `console.log` is never printed to the console

Comment: That is the correct api call: getDossierEntry(type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>(`/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/` + entryType);
}

Comment: See my answer, there is a `$` in the query template: `/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/``

Comment: But it has to be without '$' I posted the correct api call. it was my mistake.

Comment: Because is no property : patientUUID , so the correct call is: `/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/`

Comment: You're question is unclear. You want to have the UUID value in the request right ? Then, that's the way to do it in js.  See how to embed expression in js template https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199907/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-mightycode-newton).

Comment: I Understand how to do that. Oke, I do it on your way. `/api/patient/${patientUUID}/DossierEntry/`. But then of course I get this error:Cannot find name 'patientUUID'.ts(2304)